# Change domain (vhost?) on Gandi simple hosting

Tags: domain, hosting, shared-hosting, virtualhost

I have a Gandi Simple Hosting account and a domain (domain 1) which I also registered through Gandi. Gandi hosting is unfamiliar to me as it uses instances that don't have IP addresses. Currently I have my Gandi domain pointing to my hosting instance where I am in the process of developing a WordPress site.

On a completely different hosting provider I have another (traditional style with cPanel) hosting account and domain name (domain 2) where my live and active site resides.

I am in the process of redesigning my live site on Gandi and when it is ready to go live I want to point domain 2 to the instance so my site visitors should not experience any downtime.

Is this something that is possible on Gandi. I am aware that I will need to use Gandi's nameservers and also change the database entries for site url and wordpress url. My main question is if it is possible to use the original directory instance and simply switch domain 1 with domain 2.